# Python - comparing 2 identical objects returns False?

Tags: python, equality

I've defined a class as such:

```
class User:

    Name = ""
    Age = ""
    Gender = ""

    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3):
        self.Name = var1
        self.Age = var2
        self.Gender = var3

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.Name)
```

Now when I create two identical objects:

```
User1 = User("Ted", "43", "M")
User2 = User("Ted", "43", "M")
```

And attempt to compare them:

```
print(User1 == User2)
```

It returns `False`?

Comment: You also need to implement `__eq__`.

Comment: Write the equals implementation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer [Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40185133/189134) provides is correct, but incomplete.

Only overriding the `__eq__` method results in unexpected behavior when you are checking inequality.

For example, `User1 != User2` will return `True` with just the `__eq__` overridden.

You want to define both `__eq__` and `__ne__`:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, User):
        return self.Name == other.Name and \
           self.Age == other.Age and \
           self.Gender == other.Gender
    return NotImplemented

def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)
```

Now when you perform comparisons, you'll get expected results:

```
User1 = User("Ted", "43", "M")
User2 = User("Ted", "43", "M")
print(User1 != User2)
print(User1 == User2)
```

Prints:

```
False
True
```

Comment: This was just what I needed, and provides a more detailed answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to override the `__eq__` method:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, User):
        return self.Name == other.Name and \
               self.Age == other.Age and \
               self.Gender == other.Gender
    return NotImplemented
```

Comment: Maybe comment on the relationship between `__eq__` and `__hash__` since that may be the source of OP's confusion.

Comment: you can replace the ugly expression with `return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__`, right?